# can I setup svn on my home ubuntu server and make it load files to Hostgator shared account?

Tags: svn

I develop allot of web applications. I test them on local server and than upload to hostgator account.

I was thinking to setup SVN on home/test server and make it automatically upload files to shared hosting everynight.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Svn export + ftp|scp upload in post-commit hook